# netcoreapp2.1 upgrade to 3.1 leads to 502.5 error

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-3.1

I've had a deployed app on version 2.1 for a while. Locally, I'm running 3.1 with no issues. I finally deployed it and it lead to the dreaded 502.5 error. In the Azure Portal console:

`> dotnet --info` shows:

```
Version: 3.1.108
...

.NET Core SDKs installed:
<snip>
3.1.108[D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
<snip>
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.8 [D:\...]
```

Checking the version: `> dotnet --version` gives `3.1.108`

In the App Service Editor, I verified the `Web.runtimeconfig.json` shows:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "netcoreapp3.1",
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",
      "version": "3.1.8"
    },
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  }
}
```

However, it looks like `Web.deps.json` still references version `2.1`. What other configs do I need to update? I assume this is part of the issue.

Comment: Hi @NJB, how are things going? Have you tried the suggestions in my answer? Is it helpful to you? Please try it. Any progress, feel free to tell me.

Comment: Hi @BrightRan-MSFT I tried to add it, but I'm not seeing any logs. For some reason, I'm getting a 503 error on the site now, which might be why the logs aren't appearing. I don't know what happened to the configs to cause that so I'm still trying to figure that part out too. If you have suggestions, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @NJB,

You can try the following troubleshooting steps for 503 error:
1. Observe and monitor application behavior;
2. Collect data;
3. Mitigate the issue.

For detailed information, see "[**Troubleshoot HTTP 502 & 503 errors in Azure App Service**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-http-502-http-503)".

Comment: After digging into this a bit, I was still unable to resolve it. I'm not a devops person so maybe I'm just not sure what to look for. I started a new app service from scratch and that was my quickest solution. Comparing it to the old app service though, I noticed the App Service > Configuration > General Settings didn't give me the same options in the dropdowns under Stack Settings.

Answer (score 1):

The **502.5 Process Failure** error page is returned when the ASP.NET Core Module attempts to start the worker process but it fails to start. A common failure condition is the app is misconfigured due to targeting a version of the ASP.NET Core shared framework that isn't present.

The cause of a process startup failure can usually be determined from entries in the Application Event Log and the ASP.NET Core Module stdout log. You can try to set **`stdoutLogEnabled=true`** in the **`web.config`** file.

To view more details, you can reference to the articles below:

- [**502.5 Process Failure**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-5.0#5025-process-failure)
- [**When a .NET Core Azure App Service won’t start: 502.5 Process Failure**](https://stackify.com/net-core-azure-app-service-wont-start/)